# Cocos2d and the new iPhone 5 aspect ratio

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, screen-resolution, aspect-ratio, iphone-5

I have just seen the [announcment of iPhone 5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYb855lAkFs) and it says that the pixel resolution has changed to 1136*640, affecting in this way the ASPECT RATIO of the app.

How should I deal with this in my Cocos2d game? I got all the graphics done for the "old" 960*640 retina display screen and I guess that those will be distorted on the iPhone 5 screen.

Am I right? Or will there be the "old resolution" images shown without modifying the aspect ratio and leaving some screen black?

**EDIT:** Is there a way to get Cocos2d to detect if it is iPhone 5 and in that case draw the background files in the top part of the screen (top 960 pixels) and get some other custom background files to be drawn in the remaining pixels (e.g. those could be some custom ad banners or some extra buttons available in our Game only for iPhone 5).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have just added 4 inch support to my app this morning. Cocos2d runs fine (in the simulator) with no modifications. All of my scenes have resized correctly, I just had to make a few modifications to some positions as they were fixed coordinates not relative.

There is currently no way to load different images easily, I suspect there will be a new naming convention similar to -hd in the next few days.

As for your edit question, you will probably find that once you enable the 4 inch mode your layout will have a large black space at the top already. Of course you can put whatever you want there.

You can detect if it is a tall screen using

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height
```

Answer (score 6):

> iOS will automatically place thin black bars on either side of the app
>   so it remains consistent with the way the apps were originally
>   designed for previous versions of the iPhone

Several sources report this, this is [from here](http://www.gametrailers.com/mobile-apps/29109/iphone-5-revealed-available-september-21-starting-at-199).

As of yet, with no devices nor iOS 6 being available, we don't even know if or which kind of modifications would need to be done to cocos2d to support iPhone 5. Stop worrying. Don't assume. Wait and see.

As with all other devices, there will be ways to detect the exact device type. Again, this would have to wait until we get at least iOS 6. You could join the beta program in hopes of finding out, but as long as its in beta such information is under NDA and you can only find out perhaps via the private Apple developer forums.

Comment: thanks. Do you think it will be possible to get iOS 6 to  draw some custom Cocos2d layer in the "black bar" area? I would like to move my controls there for the iOS 6 devices.

Comment: to be honest I would consider it the perfect place to do some "advertisement"

Answer (score 3):

COCOS2d - v2.x

replace CCFileUtils.h and .m with following codes and add line inside delegate: `[sharedFileUtils setiPhone5DisplaySuffix:@"-568h"];         // >>>>>> iPhone 5 -568h`

.h

```
/*
 * cocos2d for iPhone: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008-2010 Ricardo Quesada
 * Copyright (c) 2011 Zynga Inc.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "../ccTypes.h"

/** Helper class to handle file operations */
@interface CCFileUtils : NSObject
{
    NSFileManager   *fileManager_;
    NSBundle        *bundle_;
    NSMutableDictionary *fullPathCache_;
    NSMutableDictionary *removeSuffixCache_;


#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
    BOOL    enableFallbackSuffixes_;

    NSString *iPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix_;
    NSString *iPhone5DisplaySuffix_;                            // <<<<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    NSString *iPadSuffix_;
    NSString *iPadRetinaDisplaySuffix_;
#endif // __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
}

/** NSBundle used by CCFileUtils. By default it uses [NSBundle mainBundle].
 @since v2.0
 */
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSBundle   *bundle;

/** NSFileManager used by CCFileUtils. By default it uses its own intance.
 @since v2.0
 */
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSFileManager  *fileManager;

#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
/** The iPhone RetinaDisplay suffixes to load resources.
 By default it is "-hd" and "" in that order.
 Only valid on iOS. Not valid for OS X.

 @since v1.1
 */
@property (nonatomic,readwrite, copy, setter = setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:) NSString *iPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix;





/** The iPhone 5 suffixes to load resources.
 By default it is "-hd" and "" in that order.
 Only valid on iOS. Not valid for OS X.

 @since v1.1
 */
@property (nonatomic,readwrite, copy, setter = setiPhone5DisplaySuffix:) NSString *iPhone5DisplaySuffix;





/** The iPad suffixes to load resources.
 By default it is "-ipad", "-hd", "", in that order.
 Only valid on iOS. Not valid for OS X.

 @since v1.1
 */
@property (nonatomic,readwrite, copy, setter = setiPadSuffix:) NSString *iPadSuffix;


/** Sets the iPad Retina Display suffixes to load resources.
 By default it is "-ipadhd", "-ipad", "-hd", "", in that order.
 Only valid on iOS. Not valid for OS X.

 @since v2.0
 */
@property (nonatomic,readwrite, copy, setter = setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:) NSString *iPadRetinaDisplaySuffix;

/** Whether of not the fallback sufixes is enabled.
 When enabled it will try to search for the following suffixes in the following order until one is found:
   * On iPad HD  : iPad HD suffix, iPad suffix, iPhone HD suffix, Without suffix
   * On iPad     : iPad suffix, iPhone HD suffix, Without suffix
   * On iPhone HD: iPhone HD suffix, Without suffix

 By default this functionality is off;
*/
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL enableFallbackSuffixes;

 #endif // __CC_PLATFORM_IOS

/** returns the shared file utils instance */
+(CCFileUtils*) sharedFileUtils;


/** Purge cached entries.
 Will be called automatically by the Director when a memory warning is received
 */
-(void) purgeCachedEntries;

/** Returns the fullpath of an filename.

 If in iPhoneRetinaDisplay mode, and a RetinaDisplay file is found, it will return that path.
 If in iPad mode, and an iPad file is found, it will return that path.

 Examples:

  * In iPad mode: "image.png" -> "/full/path/image-ipad.png" (in case the -ipad file exists)
  * In iPhone RetinaDisplay mode: "image.png" -> "/full/path/image-hd.png" (in case the -hd file exists)
  * In iPad RetinaDisplay mode: "image.png" -> "/full/path/image-ipadhd.png" (in case the -ipadhd file exists)

 */
-(NSString*) fullPathFromRelativePath:(NSString*) relPath;


/** Returns the fullpath of an filename including the resolution of the image.

 If in RetinaDisplay mode, and a RetinaDisplay file is found, it will return that path.
 If in iPad mode, and an iPad file is found, it will return that path.

 Examples:

 * In iPad mode: "image.png" -> "/full/path/image-ipad.png" (in case the -ipad file exists)
 * In iPhone RetinaDisplay mode: "image.png" -> "/full/path/image-hd.png" (in case the -hd file exists)
 * In iPad RetinaDisplay mode: "image.png" -> "/full/path/image-ipadhd.png" (in case the -ipadhd file exists)

 If an iPad file is found, it will set resolution type to kCCResolutioniPad
 If a RetinaDisplay file is found, it will set resolution type to kCCResolutionRetinaDisplay

 */
-(NSString*) fullPathFromRelativePath:(NSString*)relPath resolutionType:(ccResolutionType*)resolutionType;

#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS

/** removes the suffix from a path
 * On iPhone RetinaDisplay it will remove the -hd suffix
 * On iPad it will remove the -ipad suffix
 * On iPad RetinaDisplay it will remove the -ipadhd suffix

 Only valid on iOS. Not valid for OS X.

 @since v0.99.5
 */
-(NSString *)removeSuffixFromFile:(NSString*) path;

/** Returns whether or not a given path exists with the iPhone RetinaDisplay suffix.
 Only available on iOS. Not supported on OS X.
 @since v1.1
 */
-(BOOL) iPhoneRetinaDisplayFileExistsAtPath:(NSString*)filename;






/** Returns whether or not a given path exists with the iPhone 5 suffix.
 Only available on iOS. Not supported on OS X.
 @since v1.1
 */
-(BOOL) iPhone5DisplayFileExistsAtPath:(NSString*)filename;



/** Returns whether or not a given filename exists with the iPad suffix.
 Only available on iOS. Not supported on OS X.
 @since v1.1
 */
-(BOOL) iPadFileExistsAtPath:(NSString*)filename;

/** Returns whether or not a given filename exists with the iPad RetinaDisplay suffix.
 Only available on iOS. Not supported on OS X.
 @since v2.0
 */
-(BOOL) iPadRetinaDisplayFileExistsAtPath:(NSString*)filename;

#endif // __CC_PLATFORM_IOS

@end


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/** loads a file into memory.
 the caller should release the allocated buffer.

 @returns the size of the allocated buffer
 @since v0.99.5
 */
NSInteger ccLoadFileIntoMemory(const char *filename, unsigned char **out);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

.m

```
/*
 * cocos2d for iPhone: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008-2010 Ricardo Quesada
 * Copyright (c) 2011 Zynga Inc.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */


#import "CCFileUtils.h"
#import "../CCConfiguration.h"
#import "../ccMacros.h"
#import "../ccConfig.h"
#import "../ccTypes.h"

enum {
    kCCiPhone,
    kCCiPhoneRetinaDisplay,
    kCCiPhone5Display,
    kCCiPad,
    kCCiPadRetinaDisplay,
};

#pragma mark - Helper free functions

NSInteger ccLoadFileIntoMemory(const char *filename, unsigned char **out)
{
    NSCAssert( out, @"ccLoadFileIntoMemory: invalid 'out' parameter");
    NSCAssert( &*out, @"ccLoadFileIntoMemory: invalid 'out' parameter");

    size_t size = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if( !f ) {
        *out = NULL;
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    *out = malloc(size);
    size_t read = fread(*out, 1, size, f);
    if( read != size ) {
        free(*out);
        *out = NULL;
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(f);

    return size;
}

#pragma mark - CCCacheValue

@interface CCCacheValue : NSObject
{
    NSString            *fullpath_;
    ccResolutionType    resolutionType_;
}
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSString *fullpath;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite ) ccResolutionType resolutionType;
@end

@implementation CCCacheValue
@synthesize fullpath = fullpath_, resolutionType = resolutionType_;
-(id) initWithFullPath:(NSString*)path resolutionType:(ccResolutionType)resolutionType
{
    if( (self=[super init]) )
    {
        self.fullpath = path;
        self.resolutionType = resolutionType;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [fullpath_ release];

    [super dealloc];
}
@end

#pragma mark - CCFileUtils

#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
@interface CCFileUtils()
-(NSString *) removeSuffix:(NSString*)suffix fromPath:(NSString*)path;
-(BOOL) fileExistsAtPath:(NSString*)string withSuffix:(NSString*)suffix;
-(NSInteger) runningDevice;
@end
#endif // __CC_PLATFORM_IOS

@implementation CCFileUtils

@synthesize fileManager=fileManager_, bundle=bundle_;
#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
@synthesize iPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix = iPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix_;
@synthesize iPhone5DisplaySuffix = iPhone5DisplaySuffix_;
@synthesize iPadSuffix = iPadSuffix_;
@synthesize iPadRetinaDisplaySuffix = iPadRetinaDisplaySuffix_;
@synthesize enableFallbackSuffixes = enableFallbackSuffixes_;
#endif // __CC_PLATFORM_IOS

+ (id)sharedFileUtils
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static CCFileUtils *fileUtils = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        fileUtils = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return fileUtils;
}

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        fileManager_ = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

        fullPathCache_ = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:30];
        removeSuffixCache_ = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:30];

        bundle_ = [[NSBundle mainBundle] retain];

#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
        iPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix_ = @"-hd";
        iPhone5DisplaySuffix_ = @"-568h";
        iPadSuffix_ = @"-ipad";
        iPadRetinaDisplaySuffix_ = @"-ipadhd";

        enableFallbackSuffixes_ = NO;
#endif // __CC_PLATFORM_IOS

    }

    return self;
}

-(void) purgeCachedEntries
{
    [fullPathCache_ removeAllObjects];  
    [removeSuffixCache_ removeAllObjects];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [fileManager_ release];
    [bundle_ release];
    [fullPathCache_ release];
    [removeSuffixCache_ release];

#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS    
    [iPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix_ release];
    [iPhone5DisplaySuffix_ release];
    [iPadSuffix_ release];
    [iPadRetinaDisplaySuffix_ release];
#endif // __CC_PLATFORM_IOS

    [super dealloc];
}

-(NSString*) pathForResource:(NSString*)resource ofType:(NSString *)ext inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath
{
    return [bundle_ pathForResource:resource
                             ofType:ext
                        inDirectory:subpath];
}

-(NSString*) getPath:(NSString*)path forSuffix:(NSString*)suffix
{
    NSString *newName = path;

    // only recreate filename if suffix is valid
    if( suffix && [suffix length] > 0)
    {
        NSString *pathWithoutExtension = [path stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        NSString *name = [pathWithoutExtension lastPathComponent];

        // check if path already has the suffix.
        if( [name rangeOfString:suffix].location == NSNotFound ) {


            NSString *extension = [path pathExtension];

            if( [extension isEqualToString:@"ccz"] || [extension isEqualToString:@"gz"] )
            {
                // All ccz / gz files should be in the format filename.xxx.ccz
                // so we need to pull off the .xxx part of the extension as well
                extension = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", [pathWithoutExtension pathExtension], extension];
                pathWithoutExtension = [pathWithoutExtension stringByDeletingPathExtension];
            }


            newName = [pathWithoutExtension stringByAppendingString:suffix];
            newName = [newName stringByAppendingPathExtension:extension];
        } else
            CCLOGWARN(@"cocos2d: WARNING Filename(%@) already has the suffix %@. Using it.", name, suffix);
    }

    NSString *ret = nil;
    // only if it is not an absolute path
    if( ! [path isAbsolutePath] ) {

        // pathForResource also searches in .lproj directories. issue #1230
        NSString *imageDirectory = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

        // If the file does not exist it will return nil.
        ret = [self pathForResource:[newName lastPathComponent]
                                                   ofType:nil
                                              inDirectory:imageDirectory];
    }
    else if( [fileManager_ fileExistsAtPath:newName] )
        ret = newName;

    if( ! ret )
        CCLOGINFO(@"cocos2d: CCFileUtils: file not found: %@", [newName lastPathComponent] );

    return ret;
}

-(NSString*) fullPathFromRelativePath:(NSString*)relPath resolutionType:(ccResolutionType*)resolutionType
{
    NSAssert(relPath != nil, @"CCFileUtils: Invalid path");

    CCCacheValue *value = [fullPathCache_ objectForKey:relPath];
    if( value ) {
        *resolutionType = value.resolutionType;
        return value.fullpath;
    }

    // Initialize to non-nil
    NSString *ret = @"";

#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS

    NSInteger device = [self runningDevice];

    // iPad HD ?
    if( device == kCCiPadRetinaDisplay ) {
        ret = [self getPath:relPath forSuffix:iPadRetinaDisplaySuffix_];
        *resolutionType = kCCResolutioniPadRetinaDisplay;
    }

    // iPad ?
    if( device == kCCiPad || (enableFallbackSuffixes_ && !ret) ) {
        ret = [self getPath:relPath forSuffix:iPadSuffix_];
        *resolutionType = kCCResolutioniPad;
    }

    // iPhone HD ?
    if( device == kCCiPhoneRetinaDisplay || (enableFallbackSuffixes_ && !ret) ) {
        ret = [self getPath:relPath forSuffix:iPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix_];
        *resolutionType = kCCResolutioniPhoneRetinaDisplay;
    }

    // If it is not Phone HD, or if the previous "getPath" failed, then use iPhone images.
    if( device == kCCiPhone || !ret )
    {
        ret = [self getPath:relPath forSuffix:@""];
        *resolutionType = kCCResolutioniPhone;
    }

#elif defined(__CC_PLATFORM_MAC)

    *resolutionType = kCCResolutionMac;

    ret = [self getPath:relPath forSuffix:@""];

#endif // __CC_PLATFORM_MAC

    if( ! ret ) {
        CCLOGWARN(@"cocos2d: Warning: File not found: %@", relPath);
        ret = relPath;
    }

    value = [[CCCacheValue alloc] initWithFullPath:ret resolutionType:*resolutionType];
    [fullPathCache_ setObject:value forKey:relPath];
    [value release];

    return ret;
}

-(NSString*) fullPathFromRelativePath:(NSString*) relPath
{
    ccResolutionType ignore;
    return [self fullPathFromRelativePath:relPath resolutionType:&ignore];
}

#pragma mark CCFileUtils - Suffix (iOS only)

#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS

// XXX: Optimization: This should be called only once
-(NSInteger) runningDevice
{
    NSInteger ret=-1;

    if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if( CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 2 )
            ret = kCCiPadRetinaDisplay;
        else
            ret = kCCiPad;
    }
    else
    {
        if( CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() == 2 )

            if (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width == 640) || ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width == 1136))
            {

                ret = kCCiPhone5Display;

            } else {

                ret = kCCiPhoneRetinaDisplay;

            }
        else
            ret = kCCiPhone;
    }

    return ret;
}

-(NSString *) removeSuffix:(NSString*)suffix fromPath:(NSString*)path
{
    // quick return
    if( ! suffix || [suffix length] == 0 )
        return path;

    NSString *name = [path lastPathComponent];

    // check if path already has the suffix.
    if( [name rangeOfString:suffix].location != NSNotFound ) {

        CCLOGINFO(@"cocos2d: Filename(%@) contains %@ suffix. Removing it. See cocos2d issue #1040", path, suffix);

        NSString *newLastname = [name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:suffix withString:@""];

        NSString *pathWithoutLastname = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
        return [pathWithoutLastname stringByAppendingPathComponent:newLastname];
    }

    // suffix was not removed
    return nil;
}

-(NSString*) removeSuffixFromFile:(NSString*) path
{
    NSString *withoutSuffix = [removeSuffixCache_ objectForKey:path];
    if( withoutSuffix )
        return withoutSuffix;

    // Initial value should be non-nil
    NSString *ret = @"";

    NSInteger device = [self runningDevice];

    if( device == kCCiPadRetinaDisplay )
        ret = [self removeSuffix:iPadRetinaDisplaySuffix_ fromPath:path];

    if( device == kCCiPad || (enableFallbackSuffixes_ && !ret) )
       ret = [self removeSuffix:iPadSuffix_ fromPath:path];

    if( device == kCCiPhoneRetinaDisplay || (enableFallbackSuffixes_ && !ret) )
        ret = [self removeSuffix:iPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix_ fromPath:path];

    if( device == kCCiPhone5Display || (enableFallbackSuffixes_ && !ret) )
        ret = [self removeSuffix:iPhone5DisplaySuffix_ fromPath:path];

    if( device == kCCiPhone || !ret )
        ret = path; 

    if( ret )
        [removeSuffixCache_ setObject:ret forKey:path];

    return ret;
}

-(BOOL) fileExistsAtPath:(NSString*)relPath withSuffix:(NSString*)suffix
{
    NSString *fullpath = nil;

    // only if it is not an absolute path
    if( ! [relPath isAbsolutePath] ) {
        // pathForResource also searches in .lproj directories. issue #1230
        NSString *file = [relPath lastPathComponent];
        NSString *imageDirectory = [relPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

        fullpath = [bundle_ pathForResource:file
                                                   ofType:nil
                                              inDirectory:imageDirectory];

    }

    if (fullpath == nil)
        fullpath = relPath;

    NSString *path = [self getPath:fullpath forSuffix:suffix];

    return ( path != nil );
}

-(BOOL) iPhoneRetinaDisplayFileExistsAtPath:(NSString*)path
{
    return [self fileExistsAtPath:path withSuffix:iPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix_];
}

-(BOOL) iPhone5DisplayFileExistsAtPath:(NSString*)path
{
    return [self fileExistsAtPath:path withSuffix:iPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix_];
}

-(BOOL) iPadFileExistsAtPath:(NSString*)path
{
    return [self fileExistsAtPath:path withSuffix:iPadSuffix_];
}

-(BOOL) iPadRetinaDisplayFileExistsAtPath:(NSString*)path
{
    return [self fileExistsAtPath:path withSuffix:iPadRetinaDisplaySuffix_];
}

#endif // __CC_PLATFORM_IOS


@end
```

Comment: nevermind - it didn't work. I forgot a few things. I'll adjust it and repost it.

Comment: Sorry to be annoyingly posting this much, but after just checking on the cocos2d site, there is a new release with support for iPhone 5

Answer (score 0):

All of you suggested good solutions but there will some sort of naming convention like @2x and h@2x for ratina display and iphone 5 launch images respectively.

Thanks
Mano